# RuntimeError: cannot set daemon status of active thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, hilos

**Contexto:**

La clase ``Main()`es la encargada de ejecutar todas las funciones principales del programa, adicionalmente a esto  la clase`Hilo()` se encarga de ejecutar una función en un hilo diferente.

**Problema:**

Al iniciar el programa la primera vez se ejecuta sin problema pero cuado el programa se vuelve a ejecutar lanza el siguiente error: `raise RuntimeError("cannot set daemon status of active thread") RuntimeError: cannot set daemon status of active thread`

**Funcionamiento**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Practicas Python\Detener Hilos\TestThreading.py", line 23, in <lambda>
    self.Next.clicked.connect(lambda:self.Fun1())
  File "D:\Practicas Python\Detener Hilos\TestThreading.py", line 36, in Fun1
    self.Hilo.daemon = True
  File "C:\Users\Angel-Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 1141, in daemon
    raise RuntimeError("cannot set daemon status of active thread")
RuntimeError: cannot set daemon status of active thread
[Finished in 39.5s]
```

**Codigo:**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui
from PyQt5 import uic
import threading
import time

class Hilo(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,obj,fun):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.fun = fun
        self.obj = obj

    def run(self):
        self.fun()

class Main(QMainWindow):
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Test.ui",self)

        self.Next.clicked.connect(lambda:self.Fun1())
        self.Back.clicked.connect(lambda:self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0))
        self.signal.connect(self.Fun2)
        self.Hilo = Hilo(self,self.FunX)

    def Fun1(self):
        _movie = QtGui.QMovie("Loader.gif")
        self.label.setMovie(_movie)
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        _movie.start()



        self.Hilo.daemon = True
        self.Hilo.start()

    def FunX(self):
        print(threading.enumerate())
        time.sleep(5)
        self.signal.emit(0)

    def Fun2(self,valor):
        if valor == 0:
            self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Confirmacion.png"))
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000,lambda:self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1))
            self.Hilo._stop()
            print(threading.enumerate())

app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema como lo indica el `Traceback` es que como se esta declarando la clase `Hilo` que contiene al nuevo `thread` dentro de la funcion `__init__` el nuevo `thread` se inicia al momento de iniciar el programa y se mantiene vivo debido a que la funcion `__init__` no se ha terminado de ejecutar.

Por lo que la solución es declarar al hilo dentro de la funcion `Fun()` de esta manera de crea una nueva instancia de la clase cada vez que se oprima el botón detonante y el hilo no permanece siempre vivo o activo

```
class Main(QMainWindow):
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Test.ui",self)

        self.Next.clicked.connect(lambda:self.Fun1())
        self.Back.clicked.connect(lambda:self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0))
        self.signal.connect(self.Fun2)
        self.Hilo = Hilo(self,self.FunX) #<-- Eliminar esta linea


    def Fun1(self):
        _movie = QtGui.QMovie("Loader.gif")
        self.label.setMovie(_movie)
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        _movie.start()


        self.Hilo = Hilo(self,self.FunX) #<-- Añadir esta linea
        self.Hilo.setDaemon(True)
        self.Hilo.start()
```